# $myArray = array() vs. []

Tags: php

I found this "modern" version of defining an array in the sources of laravel 5. Are there any advantages of doing it this way?

```
// the traditional way
$arrEmpty = array();
$arrFilled = array(
    'a' => 'apple'
);

// the 'modern' way
$arrEmpty = [];
$arrFilled = [
    'a' => 'apple'
];
```

The 'new' way does not seem to be standard, so I couldn't use this one on PHP 5.3. Any doc-links are welcome.

Comment: Simpler, easier to read, similar to js syntax

Comment: *"modern" version of defining an array in laravel 5* . It is not `laravel`. It is `PHP`.

Comment: The new way is only as standard as the fact that some libraries frameworks still support older PHP versions where the short array syntax isn't available, so they can't use it

Comment: @b0s3 I know that it is PHP, I wrote _I found [...] in laravel 5_

Comment: _// the 'laravel' way $arrEmpty = [];_ Really?

Comment: Edited my question so that it is better to understand what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. [http://php.net/](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following [] is supported in PHP 5.4

Square bracket array shortcut - keys and values are separated by colons:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = ['foo': 'orange', 'bar': 'apple', 'baz': 'lemon'];
```

Square bracket array shortcut - keys and values are separated by double arrows:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = ['foo' => 'orange', 'bar' => 'apple', 'baz' => 'lemon'];
```

This is a short syntax only and in PHP < 5.4 it won't work.